# How to add a source code file as a build dependency and/or access definitions in a source file?

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, byte-buddy

I have:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.bytebuddy.byte-buddy-gradle-plugin' version "$byteBuddyVersion"
}

byteBuddy {
    transformation {
        plugin = io.github.leoframework.testing.Logger.class
    }
}
```

`Logger.java` is part of the project and in the Byte Buddy plugin. I need to reference which file/class within my build script to invoke the plugin. The class file needs to be loaded after compiling `Logger.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's part of the current project, it is not that trivial, unfortunately. Gradle is executed in its own JVM process that is run before the compilation what makes this somewhat a chicken and egg problem.

To overcome this, you'd need to compile the classes first, then define a subproject that depend on these classes dynamically and then execute the plugin from this subproject once the dependent classes are available.